# Error in Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35

Tags: unity-game-engine, socket.io, unity-webgl

I am trying to deploy a unity game to webgl. Everything works fine on windows. I am using socketio in Unity for my multiplayer game, I'm not sure if that's relevant. Also, I am using unity 2020 and I already disabled compression. I get this error in the console in chrome:

{"tid":1,"div":"EventDescriptor","msg":"Call","ex": [{"msg": "System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod::.ctor", "stack": ""}],"stack":"","ctxs":[],"t":637425122207370000,"ll":"Exception","bh":1}
(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

I don't know what that error means. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because the compiler for Web does not recognize a method.

In your case, it's `System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod`.

**Explanation:**

WebGL on Unity is AOT (Ahead of time) compiled and a method that uses reflection might not work. And it seems like you tried to use namespace `Emit` which is completely forbidden on AOT platforms including Web.

You need to remove or replace all reflection (especially `Emit`) with something that is able to compile Ahead of time!

If you did not use `Emit` or you don't know where it might come from, you should give us a full error message. `PlayerSettings -> EnableExceptions -> Full With Stacktrace`

Comment: Thanks, this helped me solve it. It was an asset I was using from the asset store